# error when install usb_cam

Tags: ros, usb-cam, camera-info-manager, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am installing usb_cam and get this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "camera_info_manager" with any of the following names:

    camera_info_managerConfig.cmake
    camera_info_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "camera_info_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "camera_info_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "camera_info_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  usb_cam/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236101/error-when-install-usb_cam/) by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Please let me know how to fix this.

I'm going to take a guess and suggest that you only `git clone`d the repository for `usb_cam`, and forgot to run a `rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src`. That would mean that all of the prerequisites of `usb_cam` haven't been installed, and CMake can't find them, causing it to show you error message you copy/pasted.

If you don't want or need to build `usb_cam` from source, I'd really recommend you just run the appropriate `sudo apt-get install ros-$DISTRO-usb-cam`.

---

Edit: `rosdep install` is really not mean to install packages themselves, that is what `apt-get` is for. It's only meant to install *dependencies* of the packages. I see a lot of questions about people seemingly trying to use it as a replacement for `apt-get` (or whatever the package manager is called for your specific platform).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-06-06**:
Thanks gvdhoorn.